# how do I deserialize ? someone could help me do this? I can not deserialize

Tags: java, serialization

Could someone help me to do this?

I can not deserialize. 
How can I deserialize this program?

List item

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        contato acon [] = new contato[3];

        acon [0] = new contato();
        acon [0].setName("joyce");
        acon [0].setAddress("hileia  n° 587");
        acon [0].setFone("789-456");
        acon [1] = new contato();
        acon [1].setName("naldo");
        acon [1].setAddress("bairro da paz n°15821");
        acon [1].setFone("654-123");
        acon [2] = new contato();
        acon [2].setName("jessica");
        acon [2].setAddress("cidade nova n°15");
        acon [2].setFone("456-789");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("contato.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(acon);
            os.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
          try {
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("contato.ser");
                ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fs);
                System.out.println(oi.readObject());

                oi.close();
                fs.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Always get error when deseralizing this object.

```
public class contato implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String fone;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setFone(String fone) {
        this.fone = fone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getFone() {
        return fone;
    }
```

Comment: How are you trying to deserialize?

Comment: in your code you are doing serialization, you have to use new `ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream())` to deserialziation

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace of the error?

Comment: You get what error? Not a real question without that.

Comment: @StinePike His code serializes an array. Your code doesn't deserialize an array. It won't work. You cannot possibly have tried it. There is no sign of the incorrect part of your code in his question, and the rest of it was already there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you that you aren't 'getting an error at all'. What you are seeing is the result of trying to print an array. This calls `System.out.println(Object)`, which calls `contato [].toString()`, which cannot be overridden, so it prints something like a class name with `[]` and a hashcode. This is to be expected. If you want to see the contents of the array you serialized you will have to deserialize it into an array object, iterate over it, and print the elements one by one.